# Importing csv file with php using the Doctrine ORM

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-odm

How do I import a csv file into a database using the Doctrine ORM classes in php? I'm a noob to this stuff. Any help would be great.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't. ORM's are for Object Relational Mapping - that is being able to tie a database record to a materialized class object.  For bulk import functionality just use, standard MySQL connection libraries (i.e. mysqli, PDO), or a CSV import script tool (there are many of these that a Google search should turn up).

Or better yet, just use MySQL `LOAD DATA INFILE` functionality and do it in a single query.